# Timeout issue in Backup-SQLDatabase cmdlet

Tags: sql-server, powershell, backup, smo

I’m trying to take back-up of a large database using “Backup-SQLDatabase” cmdlet using following statement, but I’m getting time-out error after 10 minutes.

```
{Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $Server -Database $DatabaseName -BackupFile $BackUpFile -CompressionOption On -ConnectionTimeout 0 -Initialize -Verbose -ea Stop}
```

Here’s the error exactly after 600 seconds of execution :

VERBOSE: 60 percent processed.
VERBOSE: The backup or restore was aborted.
The wait operation timed out
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Backup-SqlDatabase], Win3 
   2Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.P 
   owerShell.BackupSqlDatabaseCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

I looked up at internet and found a bug filled [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/728027/restore-sqldatabase-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation).
However, the issue still exists in SQL Server 2012 (11.0.339).

I’ve also tried reconfiguring “remote query timeout” to 0 as given [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040.aspx), but the issue persists.

This is actually very weird issue. PowerShell is for automation and scripts do take more than 10 minutes to run. “Backup-SQLDatabase” should have considered this.

Please suggest a workaround by which I can fix this while using this cmdlet.
Else , I’ve to re-write the code using SMO classes or basic T-SQL.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if no one gives a good one, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ce8f8a1-eb2c-4454-8f01-bb80150ffbac/powershell-script-to-backup-sql-databases?forum=sqltools has an implementation of SMO Backup you can start with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did some research on this and came around the following workaround :

`$serverConn = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $server
$serverConn.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0`

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -InputObject $serverConn -Database abc -BackupFile "L:\123\abc.bak"
```

When we pass Server name as a string, it tries to create it's own connection and we don't have the option to change QueryTimeout from 600 to 0.

However, we can create a SMO.Server object and use it after setting desired properties.

Hope it helps!